# R how to remove duplicates elements in the column and get average value

Tags: r

Sorry I am new to R, and the problem is quite hard for me,
Here is the matrix:

```
        V1              predictions
1   Jeffery Howes   0.0909596345057677
2   Sherilee Waring 0.00434589236424605
3   Rachel Maitland 0.0909596345057677
4   Jan Maitland    0.0909596345057677
5   Jan Maitland    0.0909596345057677
6   Jan Maitland    0.0909596345057677
7   Jan Maitland    0.0909596345057677
8   Sandra McEwen   0.0909596345057677
....
```

How can I remove the duplicates in the columns (that's okay for me, could use unique, but the following problem is quite hard for me).

For example, there are many duplicated name Jan Maitland, duplicates should be removed, **but the predications values should be calculated** (the final result left should be the average value of those duplicate names)

Could  someone help me on that? thanks a lot!!

Comment: See this post: [data.frame Group By column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799901/data-frame-group-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the dplyr library :

```
result%.%group_by(V1)%.%summarise(predictions = mean(predictions))
# the 2nd syntax
summarise(group_by(result, V1), predictions=mean(predictions))
```

hth

Comment: thanks! what's the meaning of tab? forget to mention that the matrix name is result, so it should be result%.%group_by(V1)%.%summarise(predictions = mean(predictions))??

Comment: Hi droppy, not quite understand the %.%

Comment: yes it should be result instead of tab and result must be a data.frame and a not a matrix; I'll edited the post

Comment: thanks! btw, how should I convert matrix to data.frame

Comment: as.data.frame(result)?

Comment: yes but first are you sure that result is a matrix?