# Aggregate multiple columns according to some others

Tags: r, aggregate

Having data in a data.frame, I would like to aggregate some columns (using any general function) grouping by some others, keeping the remaining ones as they are (or even omitting them). The fashion is to recall the `group by` function in `SQL`. As an example let us assume we have

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(4), b=rnorm(4), c=c("A", "B", "C", "A"))
```

and I want to sum (say) the values in column `a` and average (say) the values in column `b`, grouping by the symbols in column `c`. I am aware it is possible to achieve such using `apply`, `cbind` or similars, specifying the functions you want to use, but I was wondering if there were a smarter (one line) way (especially using the `aggregate` function) to do so.

Comment: this has been asked a gazillion times, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799901/data-frame-group-by-column and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column and here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r

Comment: @grrgrrbla Please vote to close as a duplicate in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using aggregate for multiple aggregations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-for-multiple-aggregations)

Comment: @tim biegeleisen, already did so

Comment: I have seen all the above and they all refer to aggregating only one column, which can be easily done with different syntax.

Comment: 10 seconds of search work ("aggregate by multiple columns"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-multiple-variables-simultaneously ;

Comment: If you read the above, it only refers to one kind of function (sum) for two columns, or to the use of ``cbind``, that I want to avoid.

Comment: It's not an elegant solution, but it works: `merge(aggregate( a ~ c,df,mean), aggregate( b ~ c, df, sum))`. I'm pretty sure that there must be better ways to obtain this result though.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[ , .(sum(A), mean(B)), by = C]` or using dplyr: `library(dplyr); group_by(df, C) %>% summarise(sum(A), mean(B))`

Comment: That's exactly what I have done as a workaround!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I don't follow how dealing with more than one column complicates things.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,.(sum_a = sum(a),mean_b= mean(b)),by = c]
```

Comment: What if I want to group by more than one column `c`? What would the right syntax to use be?

Comment: df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(6), b=rnorm(6), c=c("A", "B", "C", "A","D","A"), d = c(rep(letters[1:3],2))); dt <- data.table(df); dt[,.(sum_a = sum(a),mean_b= mean(b)),by = .(c,d)]

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
    mapply(Vectorize(function(x, y) aggregate(
      df[, x], by=list(df[, 3]), FUN=y), SIMPLIFY = F), 
      1:2, c('sum', 'mean'))
```

Comment: This gives me:        [,1]      [,2]     
Group.1 factor,3  factor,3 
x       Numeric,3 Numeric,3