# How to form groups in R for a bipartite graph

Tags: r

I would like to get some help with the following problem and understand how this can be done in R efficiently. The header is given in the data frame.

```
Component, TLA
C1, TLA1
C2, TLA1
C1, TLA2
C3, TLA2
C4, TLA3
C5, TLA3
```

Notice that `C1` is a component of `TLA1` and `TLA2`.

I would like to form groups of mutually exclusive subsets and create a new column called group for this subset. For the above data, the subsets and the new group column value will be like so:

```
Component, TLA, Group
C1, TLA1, 1
C2, TLA1, 1
C1, TLA2, 1
C3, TLA2, 1
C4, TLA3, 2
C5, TLA3, 2
```

Appreciate any help on this. I could have looped through the observations and tried some logic but I did not try that yet.

Comment: What is the logic for determining the group?

Comment: You should try something before you post a question.  SO is to help you when you get stuck, not do your work for you.

Comment: You can also check out this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799901/data-frame-group-by-column) link

Comment: Hello Hadd; Yes. I tried but my brain went to Perl and how in Perl I can build an anyonymous hash to perform this task. But the connections with igraph is something that I could not have thought about (that was suggested by Neal Fultz and others.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are the components of a bipartite graph. Using the `igraph` package:

```
> components(graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(df)))
$membership
   C1  TLA1    C2  TLA2    C3    C4  TLA3    C5 
    1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2 

$csize
[1] 5 3

$no
[1] 2
```

which we can plug back into the original data frame:

```
> i <- components(graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(df)))$membership
> df$group <- i[as.character(df$Component)]
> df
  Component   TLA group
1        C1  TLA1     1
2        C2  TLA1     1
3        C1  TLA2     1
4        C3  TLA2     1
5        C4  TLA3     2
6        C5  TLA3     2
```

Comment: Neal: Thanks so much for the inputs. I will take a look at igraph and then take this approach.