# R: Append column with count for a specific value

Tags: r, append, frequency

I'm looking for an easy way to subset my df and append a column with a frequency count. Suppose I have a df like this:

```
Name  
JA
JN
JA
JB
JA
JN
```

And I want to have an outcome like this:

```
 Name    Frequency 
    JA      3
    JN      2
    JB      1
```

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? It might include `split`, `by`, or `dplyr::group_by` with `dplyr::summarize`.

Comment: This can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799901/data-frame-group-by-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tally` after grouping by 'Name' with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  tally()
```

---

Or use `table` from `base R`

```
as.data.frame(table(df1[,1]))
#   Var1 Freq
#1   JA    3
#2   JB    1
#3   JN    2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
DT<-data.table(df)
DT[,.(Frequency=.N),by=Name]
```

Comment: you could shorten the code to a more efficient way: `setDT(df)[,.(Freq=.N), by=Name]`